# Fetch specific value from Regular expression extractor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have API which shows response like "ORDER_ID":"12345-45678", both the values are dynamic, I want to fetch only 45678 value and use it for further API.

I tried with following solutions in Regular expression extractor

```
"ORDER_ID":"(.{1,10})

"ORDER_ID":"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*?"

"ORDER_ID" :     \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

These solutions take only first value, not the last values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture group by brackets, so use brackets on second digits group:

```
ORDER_ID":"\d+\-(\d+)
```